# Python mocking a function globally works but local mock fails

Tags: python, mocking, code-coverage, pytest

I have a simple source file 'hello.py' under "testing_print" directory and unit test case 'test_hello.py' in "Tests" directory. Both the directories are under "test_hello_files" directory.

I am trying to write a unit test case "test_hello.py" for "hello.py" file and added a mock to it to fake the "sample_greet1" function.

If I add the mock globally the test case passes but if the mock is defined locally the test case fails.

**hello.py**

```
from import_file import sample_greet1

def greet1():
    s = 'hi'
    greet=sample_greet1(s)
    return greet
```

**test_hello.py**

```
import sys
import pytest
from mock import Mock

impo_class=sys.modules['import_file'] = Mock()
impo_class.sample_greet1 = Mock(return_value = "Prasad")  #Test case passes if the mock is here

from testing_print import hello

def test_greet1():
    print('impo_class.sample_greet1 ----', impo_class.sample_greet1())
    impo_class.sample_greet1 = Mock(return_value = "Prasad")  #Test case fails if the mock is here

    s = hello.greet1()
    assert s == 'Prasad'
```

I want to have the mocks locally inside the functions. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the patch decorator. It will automatically replace the function with a Mock object, so you don't have to import and change it manually.

The mock will be passed as a parameter to the decorated test abd it will be local. Once the function is over the Mock is removed and the original function restored.

```py
from unittest.mock import patch
from testing_print import hello

@patch('testing_print.hello.sample_greet1', return_value='Prasad')
def test_greet1(mock):
    s = hello.greet1()
    assert s == 'Prasad'
```